# If an extension method has the same signature as a method in the sealed class, what is the call precedence?

Tags: c#, c#-3.0, extension-methods

I was reading about extension methods in C# 3.0.  The text I'm reading implies that an extension method with the same signature as a method in the class being extended would be second in order of execution - that is, the method in the sealed class gets called.  If this is the case, how can you extend the sealed class ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Indeed, the *actual* method takes precedence over the extension method. And just to make it clear - "order of execution" suggests both might be called; *only* the original method will be invoked. Perhaps pick another name / signature; you can't use extension methods to monkey-patch, if that is your intent.

If there is some base-class / interface (that the type implements) that *doesn't* have this method, you could perhaps cast it to there...?

Comment: HA HA!  Monkey-patch...that's a new one.  Ok, thanks, I was thinking that if I was correct it would be breaking sealed and that would defeat the whole point of using sealed.

Comment: @Scott - also known as duck-punching. I kid you not.

Comment: Monkey-patch ... I'm adding that one to my programmer vocabulary. +1

Answer (score 7):

Use another method signature. Extension methods imply that you are extending the sealed class with new functionality and not overriding the ones already implemented.

Extension methods have "hide-by-name" semantics with instance members on a type. This means that any accessible instance member on a type will always shadow any extension methods with the same name, even if the extension method is a better fit. As a result, if an instance member is ever added to a type with the same name as an extension method, then the extension method can be rendered uncallable.

For more details, take a look at this post:
[Extension Methods Best Practices (Extension Methods Part 6)](http://blogs.msdn.com/vbteam/archive/2007/03/10/extension-methods-best-practices-extension-methods-part-6.aspx)

Comment: If you have to call the extension method with the same signature, you can call it explicitly not from the instance. `ExtensionClass.ExtendMethod(instance)`