# C# Extension method precedence

Tags: c#, .net, c#-3.0, extension-methods

I'm a bit confused about how extension methods work.

If I'm reading this correctly http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx and this [If an extension method has the same signature as a method in the sealed class, what is the call precedence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303885/if-an-extension-method-has-the-same-signature-as-a-method-in-the-sealed-class-wh).

Then the following should write out "Instance", but instead it writes "Extension method".

```
interface IFoo
{
}

class Foo : IFoo
{
    public void Say()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Instance");
    }
}

static class FooExts
{
    public static void Say(this IFoo foo)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Extension method");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IFoo foo = new Foo();
        foo.Say();
    }
}
```

Appreciate any help in clarifying the behavior.

Comment: Are you sure overriding a built-in method with an extension method compiles?

Comment: On second glance or compiling it, the interface doesn't have Say(), so what you have calls the extension method. With Save() in the interface  the compiler complains with 'C:\projects\_play\ExtensionMethods\Program.cs(2,1): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods'

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The big difference here is that you have defined an extension method for the `IFoo` interface, and your `foo` variable is of type `IFoo`.

If your code was to look like this:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.Say()
```

The Foo.Say() method would be executed, not the extension method.

I wish I could give you a thorough explanation on why this is but I can only cover the basic mechanism. As your variable was of `IFoo` type and not of `Foo`, when the compiler tried to determine what methods were available, it looked past any non-interface methods of the `Foo` class (as it should). However, the extension method `Say()` was available, so it invoked this.

Comment: To add to this, when you use `IFoo foo = ..`, the type of foo is `IFoo` even though it points to an instance of `Foo`.  `Foo foo...` calls the method on the object, `IFoo foo` causes `Say()` to Expand to `FooExts.Say(foo)`.  Run `ildasm` and drop the .exe into it to see the IL.

Answer (score 4):

In your `Main`, 
`foo` is declared as `IFoo`. When the compiler looks for a method `Say`, it finds only the extension method. This is because the instance method is declared in `Foo`, not in `IFoo`. The compiler doesn't know that the variable `foo` happens to contain a instance of `Foo`; it just looks at the type the variable is declared of.