# Stubbing and extension method in a unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I'm looking to test a method that uses code from a third party dependency.  This dependency defines and interface - IPublishedContent - that is passed a parameter to the method I want to test.

Within my method I'm calling a method on IPublishedContent called GetPropertyValue.  However this method isn't defined directly on the interface, it's added in by an extension method also provided by the third party dependency.

Given that, I [can't use Moq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562129/how-do-i-use-moq-to-mock-an-extension-method) as I normally would to mock the extension method.

Instead I figured I would create a **stub class** that implements IPublishedContent, and pass an instance of that as the parameter in my test.  I added the method I want to test as an **instance method** on my stub.

Now, my understanding was that if I have an instance method and an extension method with the same signature, it's the [instance method that gets called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303885/if-an-extension-method-has-the-same-signature-as-a-method-in-the-sealed-class-w).

But apparently not in my test - if I put a break point on the instance method in my stub it never gets called, and the test fails with an error as it's still calling into the third party extension method.

Can anyone explain why this should be the case?  I'm aware of, though not used, Microsoft Fakes (using a shim) which might be the way to solve this problem.  But I can't see why this stubbing method isn't working.  Thanks.

Comment: Are the methods exactly the same include all parameters type and return value type?

Comment: The third party library doesn't know about your added instance method. It's not a virtual method you can override in your own class.

Comment: @Aik - yes, they are.

Comment: @Rawling - that's true, and its maybe me just expecting something that isn't going to happen; but I'm not overriding it (I'm implementing an interface, not sub-classing a base class).  It seemed to me that at runtime, my test would have an instance of my stubbed class, which has an instance method with the matching signature - and hence should call that in preference to the extension method from the third party library.

Comment: For your desired behaviour you have to work with virtual function. Sadly the extension method call is static call and there is no way how to replace it once it is compiled

Answer (score 2):

Stubs do not substitute static or extension methods. You need to use shims.
 See https://stacktoheap.com/blog/2012/11/11/testing-extension-methods-with-microsoft-fakes/